# navigation along the inside surface of a sphere warps at the north pole

Tags: math, three.js, rotation, game-development, quaternions

I'm trying to create a hollow earth kind of navigation, moving along the inside surface of a sphere but there seems to be something wrong with the rotation calculation I'm doing. At the south pole turning and moving is fine but the closer you get to the north pole the more it warps so that you're facing the north pole. I'm using quaternions so it shouldn't be a gimble lock issue I think. Here is the relevant code:

```
function forwardQuaternion() {
  const q1 = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromUnitVectors(axisY(), axisUp());
  const q2 = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromAxisAngle(axisY(), playerAngle);
  return q1.multiply(q2);
}
function getForwards() {
  return axisX().applyQuaternion(forwardQuaternion());
}
```

And here is a working example https://codesandbox.io/s/threejs-playground-forked-rokm7?file=/src/index.js:2079-2259

WASD to move. If you walk forwards to the north pole (marked by a red box) and try turning away from it then as you move you warp to face it again. I've been scouring the internet for answers and tearing my hair out so if anyone has any ideas you'll have my eternal gratitude!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really rocket science, your current direction is a unit tangent vector to the sphere, to go a small step forward or backward, add a small amount of this tangent vector and project on the surface of the sphere, to rotate the current direction, vector multiply with a small exterior or interior normal vector.

Comment: If it's not really that hard, then could you edit the playground I posted to create a working example?